# Ubuntu - slow Image Viewer

Tags: 12.04

I have Dell Precision with i7 and Nvidia Quadro 2000M.

I have many 12MP (5MB JPEG) images from my camera. Image viewer on ubuntu needs 2-3 seconds to show next image. Windows 7 does the same in no-time, ps3 also, even my IPad is incredibly fast...

Is is possible to do something in order to improve performance? 
Maybe it's possible to enable hardware acceleration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Which viewer you used in Ubuntu? In my experience, Shotwell is much faster than the default Image Viewer, as the latter apparently doesn't pre-load next image.

Also this is disk operation, so if your Ubuntu running on an old drive and Windows 7 running on SSD that could make the difference too.

Cheers,

Ray

Comment: +1, I have 10k+ large images on a SSD and Shotwell flips through them as fast as I can hit the button. Eye of Gnome takes a second or two per image.

Comment: thank you - this one is super fast! I was using default one from Ubuntu plus I've tried few others... but not Shotwell ;)